# WildFly does not find @Default bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly

I have a set of modules; a couple of them define shared interfaces and the others provide implementations to them.

In one of my classes I try to inject 4 interfaces; two of them are giving me lots of trouble for unknown reasons.

So, in `ControladorProcesoFirma` I have:

```
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces.IApiPortaFib;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces.IControladorCopiaDigitalAutentica;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces.IControladorCustodia;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces.IFileManager;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces.IGestorPersistencia;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.public_interfaces.EstadoProcesoFirma;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.public_interfaces.IControladorProcesoFirma;
...
@Default
public class ControladorProcesoFirma
    implements IControladorProcesoFirma {

    @Inject
    private IApiPortaFib apiPortaFib;

    @Inject 
    private IGestorPersistencia gestorPersistencia;

    @Inject
    private IControladorCustodia controladorCustodia;

    @Inject
    private IControladorCopiaDigitalAutentica controladorCopiaDigitalAutentica;

    @Inject
    private IFileManager gestorFicheros;
    ...
}
```

Now, in Eclipse the two first `@Inject` show me a warning about 'JSR-346: No bean eligible for injection`, yet I am little worried since the project does not have a dependency to the project that has both implementations.

The interfaces affected are:

```
package es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces;

import java.io.InputStream;

import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.public_interfaces.IProcesoFirma;

public interface IApiPortaFib {
   public Long enviarProcesoPortaFib(
       IProcesoFirma procesoFirma,
       InputStream contenidoFicheroOriginal);

   public InputStream recuperarFicheroFirmado(
       Long idPortaFib);
}
```

and

```
package es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces;

import java.util.Collection;

import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.public_interfaces.IProcesoFirma;

public interface IGestorPersistencia {
    public IProcesoFirma persistir(
        IProcesoFirma procesoFirma);

    public IProcesoFirma recuperar(
        Long idProcesoFirma);

    public Collection<? extends IProcesoFirma> recuperarTodos();
}
```

and, in two separate projects, I have the implementations (which I have stripped to the bare minimum):

```
package es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.portafib_bridge.api;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces.IApiPortaFib;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.public_interfaces.IProcesoFirma;

@Default
public class ApiPortaFib
    implements IApiPortaFib {

    private static final Logger LOG =
        Logger.
            getLogger(
                ApiPortaFib.
                    class.
                    getName());

    @Inject
    private IConfiguracionPortaFIB configuracionPortaFIB;

    public ApiPortaFib() {
    }

    @Override
    public Long enviarProcesoPortaFib(
        IProcesoFirma procesoFirma,
        InputStream contenidoFichero) {
        return 0L;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream recuperarFicheroFirmado(
        Long idPortaFib) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
package es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.persistencia_memoria;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;

import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.private_interfaces.IGestorPersistencia;
import es.ssib.otic.inte_portafib.public_interfaces.IProcesoFirma;

@Default
public class GestorPersistencia
    implements IGestorPersistencia {

    @Override
    public IProcesoFirma persistir(
        IProcesoFirma procesoFirma) {

        return procesoFirma;
    }

    @Override
    public IProcesoFirma recuperar(
        Long idProcesoFirma) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends IProcesoFirma> recuperarTodos() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

All the interfaces and implementations are packaged as `jar`, each with a bare `META-INF/beans.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans
    bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"/>
```

Finally, all the application is packaged as a .war, also with a `WEB-INF/beans.xml` file.

When it deploys, it fails to find either of these two CDI beans for injection as attribute, despite that the jars have been included in the war. What is more strange, just by commenting the two `@Inject` annotations, the application (which happens quite a few more CDI beans) deploy successfully).

What am I doing wrong?

The server is JBoss WildFly 9.0.2 on Windows.

Comment: You've mentioned that beans with `@Default` annotation are located in separate projects. Are you sure that those projects (submodules?) are also packaged into WAR archive?

Comment: @Ajan yes they all appear in `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your implementations are not annotated with *Bean defining annotations* ([link](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations)). `@Default` is just a qualifier. What you can do is to annotate `GestorPersistencia` and `ApiPortaFib` with `@Dependent`. Another solution is to use `bean-discovery-mode="all"`

Comment: Thank you, I still have to read some more on these annotations and why it sometimes works without them, but now it works like it should.